# Show the selected row record in textbox/label

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox, label

How do I make the selected row record from a `DataGridView` show in a `TextBox`? I got some `TextBox` and `Label` in a `Form`. I want the text inside the `TextBox/Label` to change when the user selects a row record from the `DataGridView`. I tried the following code to make it happen, but it doesn't work

```
private void ItemTable_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    label_itemid_show.Text = ItemTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    text_itemname.Text = ItemTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    text_itemprice.Text = ItemTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    text_itemstock.Text = ItemTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: WPF or WinForms?

Comment: "It doesn't work", does it do anything?

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar WinForms

Comment: @Foitn I don't think so. After clicking the button, there are nothing changed in form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on a project that includes a features similar to yours. Currently I select a record in a datagridview and need to show it's values to textboxes so that any values can be edited.

This is how I tackle the problem.

```
Models.Item item = DAL.ItemDAL.GetItem(Convert.ToInt32(ItemDataGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value));
        tbModifyItemID.Text = Convert.ToString(item.ItemID);
        tbModifyItemName.Text = item.ItemName;
```

It's the ItemDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value that finds me the ItemID of the selected record.

In your case it's [DataGridName].CurrentRow.Cells[FieldNo, starting at 0].Value.ToString();

This allows you to click on any cell in the record and still retrieve the specified cell in the code.

Hope it helps c:

PS:
If you put it inside a

```
private void ItemDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

method it will run the code anytime you click a different cell in the datagridview.

Comment: May I ask what DAL and models are? Is that a reference or something?

Comment: DAL and Models are just Folder names. DAL for Data Access Layer and Models for all of the objects I'm using @Knugi

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
lblDetails.Text = dgMainGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

lblDetails: A label on the form.
dgMainGrid: DataGrivView on the form.

PS: Just make sure you select the row inside the datagrid and not any particular cell, row selecting is done by clicking on the left of your first column i.e. the row selector column which gets added at the run time in WinForms.

Comment: Just put it inside"private void ItemTable_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)"?